# Convert column into row

Tags: r

I would like to convert a column into row. Thus I use the function "reshape" to do it. More precisely, I have:

```
`n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)`
```

The thing is that I have several values of "s" (always the same are repeated) for each "n".

I use:

```
reshape(df, idvar = "s", ,direction = "wide", varying = list("b"))
```

I am making a mistake somewhere but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example using `dput` and not with `images`.  Also, the image is not clear with lots of blanks.

Comment: Look into na.locf from zoo package, then [reshape data from long to wide format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `cbind.data.frame()` along with `table()` function

```
> df <- data.frame(Country = c("Aus","Ind","NZ"), Year= c(1956,1957,1958))
> df
   Country Year
 1     Aus 1956
 2     Ind 1957
 3      NZ 1958

> table(cbind.data.frame(df$Country,df$Year))
               df$Year
df$Country 1956 1957 1958
       Aus    1    0    0
       Ind    0    1    0
       NZ     0    0    1
```